# Iterate over a pandas DataFrame, using groupby, and select values based off condition in each group

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame with many groups. 
What I want to do is iterate over each group, and depending on if a certain condition is met, I want to sum up values for that group.

My DataFrame looks something like this:

```
 Item_Num   Price_Change   Unit_Sales
 10                 True           10
 10                 False          15
 10                 False          11
 10                 False          13
 12                 True           10 
 12                 False          11
 12                 False          14
 12                 True           11
 12                 False          11
```

For each group of Item_Num, I want to record the sum of unit sales when there was a price change from that row and on until there is another price change. So, I want results like this:

```
 0 Item_Num   Price_Change   Unit_Sales  Sum 
 1 10                 True           10   49
 2 10                 False          15  
 3 10                 False          11
 4 10                 False          13
 5 12                 True           10   34
 6 12                 False          11
 7 12                 False          14
 8 12                 True           11   22
 9 12                 False          11
```

(So I'm getting the sum of 49 by summing rows 1 through 4, getting sum of 34 by summing rows 5-7, and getting sum 22 by summing rows 8 and 9).

Here's what I have so far (sketch):

```
 for name, group in new.groupby('UPC'):
     if ['Price_Change'] == True:
          sum(unit_sales until next price change)
```

What's the best way to iterate through each group (can my method be improved) and how can I select the row where Price_Change == True?

Comment: Also I don't want to necessarily create a new column of 'Sum'. Are using indexes a good idea (i.e. where index == True etc) ?

Answer (score 1):

Very close to your previous question :-)

```
df['New']=df.groupby([df['Item_Num'],df['Price_Change'].cumsum()])['Unit_Sales'].transform('sum')
df
Out[15]: 
   Item_Num  Price_Change  Unit_Sales  New
0        10          True          10   49
1        10         False          15   49
2        10         False          11   49
3        10         False          13   49
4        12          True          10   35
5        12         False          11   35
6        12         False          14   35
7        12          True          11   22
8        12         False          11   22
df.New=df.New.where(df['Price_Change'],'')
df
Out[17]: 
   Item_Num  Price_Change  Unit_Sales New
0        10          True          10  49
1        10         False          15    
2        10         False          11    
3        10         False          13    
4        12          True          10  35
5        12         False          11    
6        12         False          14    
7        12          True          11  22
8        12         False          11
```

Comment: Hi @Wen! Thank you! I know its similar to my previous question, but I really wanted to iterate with a for loop for the DataFrame. I plan on applying more calculations later, which is why I want a for loop version of this. :)

Comment: @Hana if you with pandas , it is better do not using for loop .